# spark map operation changes schema

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, scalatest

This has me confused.  I'm using "spark-testing-base_2.11" % "2.0.0_0.5.0" for the test.  Can anyone explain why the map function changes the schema if using a Dataset, but works if I use the RDD?  Any insights greatly appreciated.

```
import com.holdenkarau.spark.testing.SharedSparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.{ Encoders, SparkSession }
import org.scalatest.{ FunSpec, Matchers }

class TransformSpec extends FunSpec with Matchers with SharedSparkContext {
  describe("data transformation") {
    it("the rdd maintains the schema") {
      val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
      import spark.implicits._

      val personEncoder = Encoders.product[TestPerson]
      val personDS = Seq(TestPerson("JoeBob", 29)).toDS
      personDS.schema shouldEqual personEncoder.schema

      val mappedSet = personDS.rdd.map { p: TestPerson => p.copy(age = p.age + 1) }.toDS
      personEncoder.schema shouldEqual mappedSet.schema
    }

    it("datasets choke on explicit schema") {
      val spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
      import spark.implicits._

      val personEncoder = Encoders.product[TestPerson]
      val personDS = Seq(TestPerson("JoeBob", 29)).toDS

      personDS.schema shouldEqual personEncoder.schema

      val mappedSet = personDS.map[TestPerson] { p: TestPerson => p.copy(age = p.age + 1) }
      personEncoder.schema shouldEqual mappedSet.schema
    }
  }
}

case class TestPerson(name: String, age: Int)
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things are conspiring against you here.  Spark appears to have special casing for what types it considers nullable.

```
case class TestTypes(
        scalaString: String, 
        javaString: java.lang.String,
        myString: MyString,
        scalaInt: Int,
        javaInt: java.lang.Integer,
        myInt: MyInt
    )

    Encoders.product[TestTypes].schema.printTreeString results in:
    root
     |-- scalaString: string (nullable = true)
     |-- javaString: string (nullable = true)
     |-- myString: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
     |-- scalaInt: integer (nullable = false)
     |-- javaInt: integer (nullable = true)
     |-- myInt: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |-- value: integer (nullable = false)
```

but if you map the types you will end up with everything nullable

```
val testTypes: Seq[TestTypes] = Nil
val testDS = testTypes.toDS
testDS.map(foo => foo).mapped.schema.printTreeString results in everything being nullable:
root
 |-- scalaString: string (nullable = true)
 |-- javaString: string (nullable = true)
 |-- myString: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- scalaInt: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- javaInt: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- myInt: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- value: integer (nullable = true)
```

2. Even if you force the schema to be correct, Spark explicitely ignores nullability comparisons when applying a schema, which is why when you convert back to the typed representation you lose the few nullability guarantees you had.

You could enrich your types to be able to force a nonNull schema:

```
implicit class StructImprovements(s: StructType) {
    def nonNull: StructType = StructType(s.map(_.copy(nullable = false)))
  }

 implicit class DsImprovements[T: Encoder](ds: Dataset[T]) {
    def nonNull: Dataset[T] = {
      val nnSchema = ds.schema.nonNull
      applySchema(ds.toDF, nnSchema).as[T]
    }
  }

val mappedSet = personDS.map { p =>
    p.copy(age = p.age + 1)
  }.nonNull
```

But you will find it evaporates when applying any interesting operation then when comparing schemas again if the shape is the same except nullability Spark will pass it through as the same.

This appears to be by design https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/11785

Answer (score 0):

A map is a transformation operation on the data. It takes the input, and a function and applies that function to all elements of the input data. The output is the set of return values of this function.  So the schmea of the output data is dependant on the return type of the function. 
The map operation is a fairly standard and heavily used operation in functional programming. Look at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function) if you want to read more.

Comment: Hi Tapan.  I am familiar with what map does. I am wanting to modify a set of records (look at the example, it takes a TestPerson, and adds a year to their age).  However, if you look at the schema of the returned TestPerson, it differs from what the system says it will be (personEncoder).  What I do not understand is WHY it changed the schema.  Thanx.